# How can we change the EoS (to PR using the Flags function) for REFPROP used within Mathematica?

Tags: functions, warning-messages, special-functions, librarylink, api

I would like to change the EoS used by REFPROP to the PR EoS for several calculations.

It's stated that the **Flags** function must be used.

"

> Peng-Robinson   or PR 0: Turn off the Peng-Robinson equation of state
> (default). 2: Use Peng-Robinson equation for all calculations. 3: Use
> Peng-Robinson with translation term deactivated. This option is never
> reset.

"

I guess I have to use `Flags["PR", 3]`
However, I'm unsure where to place/call it within the typical Refprop[] function.

```
T = 290 K;
P = 2036 kPa;
RefProp["CO2", "TP", "H", T, P]
```

---

Also, I get an error when I try the Flags function examples:

```
Flags["Dir search", -999]
```

NET::methodargs: Improper arguments supplied for method named FLAGSdll.

Could someone guide me on **how to use the Flags function** to *switch the EoS to the PR EoS* and also **where to place or call the Flags** function?

Thank you.

Comment: Link to documentation for the stated software is [here](https://pages.nist.gov/REFPROP-docs/).

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. I initially suggested that this question could be answered on the Chemistry SE due to my ignorance of the Chemistry features in Mathematica. Please wait for an answer.  Regards.